# Laravel Eloquent(where clauses)

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Whats the difference between '<>' and '!=' in laravel eloquent?

```
->where("payed",'<>',2)
```

this gave me empty array, but when i tried the below:

```
->where(function ($query){
    $query->where('payed','!=',2)
        ->orWhere('payed',null);
})
```

it works

```
->where("payed",'<>',2)
```

Comment: they have the same meaning in mysql, the `!=` used to not exist but was added a while ago

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This `'<>'` and `'!='` is "**not equal**" in terms of SQL.](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/comparision-functions-and-operators/not-equal-operator.php)

But the difference is the result

1. In `->where("payed",'<>',2)`, you're checking for records where `'payed'` is not equal to 2. If `'payed'` **is null, it will not be returned** because null is not compared with 2.
2. In the second query, you're checking for records where `'payed'` is not equal to 2 OR `'payed'` is null. This means **it includes the records where `'payed'` is null**

---

So if you want to include `null` values in first query you have to use

```
->where('payed', '<>', 2)->orWhereNull('payed')
```